# Printer.GetPrinter raises an exception in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm trying to print a series of labels to a Zebra S4M printer, for some reason the page height seems to be stuck on 5 cm and I need it to be 6.8 cm.

I am trying to set the Paper size using the following code

```
var
  FDevice: PChar;
  FDriver: PChar;
  FPort: PChar;
  DeviceMode: THandle;
  DevMode: PDeviceMode;
begin
  {to get a current printer settings}
  Printer.GetPrinter(FDevice, FDriver, FPort, DeviceMode);
  {lock a printer device}
  DevMode := GlobalLock(DeviceMode);
  DevMode^.dmPaperSize := 0;
  DevMode^.dmPaperWidth := fBaseSettings.Width;
  DevMode^.dmPaperLength := fBaseSettings.Height;
  Printer.SetPrinter(FDevice, FDriver, FPort, DeviceMode);
  {unlock a device}
  GlobalUnlock(DeviceMode);
end;
```

where fBaseSettings contains the target Label dimensions (amongst other things), but I keep getting an error message 
`Project SPXLabels.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x00rred82: write of address 0x59212b17`

I can't see what I am doing wrong! Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Please can you report the true error message. Please don't fake it! Ask yourself also why you did not check for errors. Are you 100% sure that `GlobalLock` always returns a valid pointer? Do the docs guarantee that? Or is it possible that `DevMode` could be `nil`? Why do people not check for errors? It's the copy/paste culture, run first, think later.

Comment: That is the true error message! as for the GlobalLock/Unlock, it doesn't get that far, failing at the Printer.GetPrinter statement!

Comment: `0x00rred82` doesn't look right. If that really is the error message, then something very weird is going on!

Comment: If you check the XE2 Help it simply states that the GetPrinter method fills the passed in parameters with information about the current printer. The Printer object had been set to a valid printer prior to the call to this code block (I also tried inserting the code into the calling code in case the Printer object was getting 'lost' in the call).

Comment: Sorry bad case of touch typing :-( should have been 0x0044ed82 - not that that's going to help much :-)

Comment: Why are you typing? Always use paste error messages verbatim. And it might have helped. If the address matched the offset to `dmPaperSize` then we'd know that `DevMode` was `nil`.

Comment: I think I may have found the problem - the code crashes in the TPrinter.GetPrinter method when it tries to to get the Port

Answer (score 5):

FDevice, FDriver and FPort are pointers to a string that you pass in to get the data back. Thus you must first allowcate memory for this.

try this

```
var 
  FDevice, FDriver, FPort: string;
begin
  SetLength(FDevice, 200);
  SetLength(FDriver, 200);
  SetLength(FPort, 200);
  {to get a current printer settings}
  Printer.GetPrinter(PChar(FDevice), PChar(FDriver), PChar(FPort), DeviceMode);
```

Comment: You need to typecast to PChar, if you're using String... or you can just use `FDevice, FDriver, FPort: array[0..255] of char`... no need to `SetLength` this way.

Comment: Thanks Larsdk, it's always the obvious that bites you in the bum!

Comment: Gah, can't believe I didn't spot that!! Surely you need to find a better way to work out the lengths required. And wouldn't static buffers be simpler?

Comment: FWIW, this API is pretty close to impossible to use. How on earth can you be expected to know how much space to allocate for these three strings? It's ridiculous!

Comment: @David: See the WinAPI function `GetPrinter`. Then see `TPrinter.GetPrinters`. Then decide to use 255 char buffers for `FDevice`, `FDriver`, and `FPort`. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I cannot see any reason why 255 should be enough, I don't follow your logic

Comment: @David: Look at the complexity involved in using `Windows.GetPrinter`, and the hoops that they go through with `EnumPrinters`. Then ask yourself how often you've seen a printer name, driver name, or printer port name exceed 255 characters. I can tell you I never have (since the port and device are separated). Use `EnumPrinters` yourself and tell me what you would have done if you were Borland writing `Printer.GetPrinter`.

Comment: @KenWhite Sure, it should be fine. Kind of galling though when you consider that `TPrinter.GetPrinter` is actually returning values held in `string` objects, and seems to perversely go out of its way to encourage buffer overrun. Emba could readily have just returned strings and everyone would be happy.

Comment: @David: At the time the Printers unit was written (Delphi 1), I was quite happy with being able to print without writing all of that code myself.

Comment: @KenWhite I just think that an interface that begs for buffer overrun is badly thought out. I'm sure everyone would agree that returning three strings is better than asking the caller to allocate some memory and hope for the best.

Comment: I of course agree with various comments about using array of char and/or finding out the right buffer size etc. I was in a hurry and just wanted to point out that it was a memory allocation problem.